# AWS Athena - Get QueryExecutionIds of current date

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, pagination, amazon-athena

I want to extract the execution Id's of queries that have ran on the current date from Athena. There is no limit to what the number of queries can be.

I am using the following code to extract the Id's. But, I cannot figure out a way to stop the pagination once I get the Id's of the queries that ran on the current date. Is there a way to get the queries for only the current date?

Also, here I have given a specific number for `MaxItems`. Can this be made dynamic?

```
client = boto3.client('athena')
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_query_executions')
response_iterator = paginator.paginate(           
                              PaginationConfig={
                                 'MaxItems': 1000, 
                                 'PageSize': 50
                              }
                   )
for page in response_iterator:
   print(page['QueryExecutionIds'])
```

Answer (score 2):

As John mentioned in his answer there is no direct way for you to filter the execution ids based on date. But once you get the list of execution ids from `list_query_executions` method then you pass this list to [`batch_get_query_execution`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.batch_get_query_execution) method.

This will return information about each execution id which also includes `SubmissionDateTime` and `CompletionDateTime` for each query. Now you can apply filter on any of this field matching current date. If there are more than 50 execution ids then you need to do in multiple iterations using for loop

Comment: Okay thanks. Is there a way to make the 'MaxItems' a dynamic number? As in, it gets 1000 records in every loop until the loop is ended forcefully?

Comment: unfortunately the limit is at API level so at max there can be 50 for each call https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/APIReference/API_ListQueryExecutions.html#athena-ListQueryExecutions-request-MaxResults

Answer (score 1):

The `list_query_executions()` command does not offer a date filter.

Therefore, you will need to filter the results within your Python code.

You can stop the pagination by breaking out of the `for` loop.

Comment: Okay. What about the 'MaxItems' field?'

Comment: That's a feature of the [paginator](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html).